# Mysql optimization based on explain

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing, explain

I have the following query that takes a really long time to execute. I need to speed it up, but I'm at a lost as to what technique to use. This is the query:

```
SELECT 
    `User`.`id`, 
    `User`.`username`, 
    `User`.`password`, 
    `User`.`role`, 
    `User`.`created`, 
    `User`.`modified`, 
    `User`.`email`, 
    `User`.`other_user_id`, 
    `User`.`first_name`, 
    `User`.`last_name`, 
    `User`.`place_id`, 
    `Resume`.`id`, 
    `Resume`.`user_id`, 
    `Resume`.`other_resume_id`, 
    `Resume`.`other_user_id`, 
    `Resume`.`file_extension`, 
    `Resume`.`created`, 
    `Resume`.`modified`, 
    `Resume`.`is_deleted`, 
    `Resume`.`has_file`, 
    `Resume`.`is_stamped`, 
    `Resume`.`is_active` 
FROM 
    `streetofwalls`.`users` AS `User` 
    LEFT JOIN `my_database`.`attempts` AS `Attempt` 
        ON (`Attempt`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` AND `Attempt`.`test_id` != 5) 
    LEFT JOIN `my_database`.`reports` AS `Resume` 
        ON (`Resume`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE 
    `Attempt`.`test_id` = 8 
    AND `Attempt`.`score` > 60 
    AND `User`.`id` IN (
        SELECT 
            `User1`.`id` 
        FROM 
            `my_database`.`users` AS User1 
            LEFT JOIN `my_database`.`tags_users` AS TagUser 
                ON (`User1`.`id`= `TagUser`.`user_id`) 
            LEFT JOIN `my_database`.`tags` AS Tag 
                ON (`TagUser`.`tag_id`= `Tag`.`id`) 
        WHERE `Tag`.`id` = (8) ) 
    AND `User`.`id` NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            `User1`.`id` 
        FROM 
            `my_database`.`users` AS User1 
            LEFT JOIN `my_database`.`tags_users` AS TagUser 
                ON (`User1`.`id`= `TagUser`.`user_id`) 
            LEFT JOIN `my_database`.`tags` AS Tag 
                ON (`TagUser`.`tag_id`= `Tag`.`id`) 
        WHERE `Tag`.`id` = (3) ) 
    AND `Resume`.`has_file` = 1 
GROUP BY `User`.`id` 
ORDER BY `Attempt`.`score` DESC;
```

This query generates the following explain:
[image: explain for the above query]

As you can see, I have several indexes on this query. At the moment only the resume table is not able to be indexed. Is is possible to index this table in the context of this query? Is there some other way to speed this query up that I have not thought of? Its prohibitively slow for its intended function and I'm out of ideas. Thank you to anyone who can help. Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: To be blunt, this is a really confused query, and that should be fixed before you try to optimize it; I can't readily tell its intended purpose. Some confusing things: a) you are doing left joins but then putting restrictions in the where clause, effectively rendering them inner joins. b) I can't easily tell why you are using GROUP BY as there are no aggregate function being used, and thus the resulting data is indeterminate, one the more ugly features of MySQL. Can you provide sample data and desired output?

Comment: As pointed by @RedFilter the WHERE clause effectively removes the need for LEFT JOINs in the main query. Also the WHERE clause suggests that the user must have a Tag = 8 and must not have a tag = 3. This could be obtained by more effective means that LEFT JOINs.

Comment: I'd pay attention to RedFilters comment...but from a putrely optimization standpoint, you culprit is most likely the select statements in your where clause.  MySQL preforms subselects in where clauses horribly poorly and is usually best written as a join instead of in the where clause.

Comment: Okay, I agree with what everyone is saying. I'm going to start looking  into your suggestions.

Comment: You should consider using EXISTS instead of IN - it should definitely speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

try inner join instead of sub-query 
it is default to guide query without running on data,but may be following the query will help you.

SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`other_user_id`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`place_id`, `Resume`.`id`, `Resume`.`user_id`, `Resume`.`other_resume_id`, `Resume`.`other_user_id`, `Resume`.`file_extension`, `Resume`.`created`, `Resume`.`modified`, `Resume`.`is_deleted`, `Resume`.`has_file`, `Resume`.`is_stamped`, `Resume`.`is_active`

FROM 
    `streetofwalls`.`users` AS `User`
LEFT JOIN `my_database`.`attempts` AS `Attempt` ON (`Attempt`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` AND `Attempt`.`test_id` != 5) 
LEFT JOIN `my_database`.`reports` AS `Resume` ON (`Resume`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)

, `my_database`.`users` AS User1

LEFT JOIN `my_database`.`tags_users` AS TagUser on (`User1`.`id`= `TagUser`.`user_id`)

LEFT JOIN `my_database`.`tags` AS Tag  ON (`TagUser`.`tag_id`= `Tag`.`id`)

WHERE 
    `User`.`id` = `User1`.`id`
    AND `Attempt`.`test_id` = 8 
    AND `Attempt`.`score` > 60
    AND `Resume`.`has_file` = 1 
    AND `Tag`.`id` = '8'  AND `Tag`.`id` != '3'
GROUP BY `User`.`id` 
ORDER BY `Attempt`.`score` DESC;