# Why is this MySQL query so slow?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

We're working really hard to get this query to run in a tolerable amount of time:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`,
FROM `users` AS `User` 
LEFT JOIN `attempts` AS `Attempt` ON (`Attempt`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` AND `Attempt`.`test_id` != 875) 
LEFT JOIN `resumes` AS `Resume` ON (`Resume`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE `Attempt`.`test_id` = 964 AND `Attempt`.`score` > 10 AND `Resume`.`has_file` = 1 AND `Resume`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`
```

There are approximately 50,000 total user rows.

The query is almost instantaneous when there is a `LIMIT` of 1000 or less. But if the limit is not present it times out after 300 seconds (the max allowed on our testing environment).

We need to be able to return all of the result from the query in preferably 10 seconds or less. At times this will be around 10,000 records. Is this unrealistic? Or are we doing something sub-optimal that is making this query so slow.

If it's relevant, when I run this query from the command line (not through my PHP app) it is very fast, even when returning 10K records.

*Update: * `EXPLAIN` shows that indexes are not getting used for one of the joined tables

Comment: try running EXPLAIN and see if it uses the correct indexes

Comment: Why do you need 10,000 rows on the client? Don't you want to page your data?

Comment: This isn't your query. Further, your WHERE conditions render ALL your OUTER JOINS as INNER JOINS, so you might as well write them that way to begin with.

Comment: This looks a lot like this question and suffers from similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248803/mysql-optimization-based-on-explain#comment30201197_20248803

Comment: You should ditch ` AND `Attempt`.`test_id` != 875 ` as you already have a restrictive WHERE clause and you also don't need `AND `Resume`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` ` in the WHERE clause since it's on a join (alternatively, make the join an INNER JOIN)

Comment: If the query runs fast from the command line and slow from php it is obvious where the bottleneck is. Maybe you are processing rows one by one in your code after the query is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses are horribly confused, like the question referenced in my comment above.

Try this:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`
FROM `users` AS `User` 
INNER JOIN `attempts` AS `Attempt` ON `Attempt`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `resumes` AS `Resume` ON `Resume`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`
WHERE `Attempt`.`test_id` = 964 
    AND `Attempt`.`score` > 10 
    AND `Resume`.`has_file` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have good indices you should avoid criteria like these:

```
`Attempt`.`test_id` != 875
`Attempt`.`score` > 10
```

and replaces them with IN() or something like

```
`Attempt`.`test_id` = 964
```

Comment: Are you sure that `IN()` is faster? I was taught to avoid subqueries whenever possible.

Comment: I mean IN(id1, id2, id3...) not IN(SELECT ...)