# CakePHP: Is it possible to force find() to run a single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP 2.x. When I inspect the sql dump, I notice that it's "automagic" is causing one of my `find()`s to run several separate SELECT queries (and then presumably merging them all together into a single pretty array of data).

This is normally fine, but I need to run one very large query on a table of 10K rows with several joins, and this is proving too much for the magic to handle because when I try to construct it through `find('all', $conditions)` the query times out after 300 seconds. But when I write an equivalent query manually with JOINS, it runs very fast.

My theory is that whatever PHP "magic" is required to weave the separate queries together is causing a bottleneck for this one large query.

1. Is my theory a plausible explanation for what's going on?
2. Is there a way to tell Cake to just keep it simple and make one big fat SELECT instead of it's fancy automagic?

**Update:** I forgot to mention that I already know about `$this->Model->query();` Using this is how I figured out that the slow-down was coming from PHP magic. It works when we do it this way, but it feels a little clunky to maintain the same query in two different forms. That's why I was hoping CakePHP offered an alternative to the way it builds up big queries from multiple smaller ones.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170852/how-to-create-custom-mysql-queries-in-cakephp

Comment: @przeqpiciel Thanks. I know about `$this->Model->query()`. It's a suitable alternative, but I was hoping not to "throw out the baby with the bathwater" by doing it all by hand with manual SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this where you query tables with 10k records you shouldn't be doing a find('all') without limiting the associations, these are some of the strategies you can apply:

1. Set recursive to 0 If you don't need related models
2. Use [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containable) to bring only the associated models you need.
3. Apply limits to your query
4. Caching is a good friend
5. [Create and destroy associations on the fly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly) As you need.

Since you didn't specify the problem I just gave you general ideas to apply depending on the problem you have

Comment: Thanks but this does not help with my question. I need to get ALL the records and some data in associated tables. I've stripped down the query as much as possible using the `$options` array, but just not doing it at all isn't an option.

Comment: can you share the associations you have and the data that you need? Maybe we can improve the performance of your query. We can't help you if we don't see any code.

Comment: I've posted a different question about trying to optimize the query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333276/why-is-this-mysql-query-so-slow